# Typescript Bidirectional Inference/Constraint

Tags: typescript

Sorry about the vague title, I spend a decent 30 minutes trying to think of how to cleanly summarise this and I can't think of anything better.

So, after removing all the business logic, the situation I would like to achieve looks something like this:

```js
const Func: <
  T extends (PartA & PartB & PartC),
  PartA extends Partial<T> = {},
  PartB extends Partial<T> = {},
  PartC extends Partial<T> = {}
> (parts: { partA: PartA, partB: PartB, partC: PartC }) => T;
```

Essentially the aim here is to have `T` be optional, such that if `Func()` is called without `T`, then `T` will be inferred from the structures of `PartA`, `PartB`, and `PartC`, and if `T` *is* passed (as `Func<T>()`), then it will be used to constrain the types of `PartA`, `PartB`, and `PartC`.

But of course I can't do it as I set it up in the example above, because that causes `T` to be a circular constraint, and I can't think of any way around that. But I also know that there are various tools in TS like `infer` and such that might be useful if I knew how to implement them properly. So, does anyone know of a way in which I can manipulate the way these generics are defined in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the definiton like this:

```
const func: <
  T extends (A & B & C),
  A = unknown,
  B = unknown,
  C = unknown
> (parts: { 
  partA: A & Partial<T>, 
  partB: B & Partial<T>, 
  partC: C & Partial<T> 
}) => T = null!;
```

The three generic types `A`, `B` and `C` get a default value of `unknown` to make them *optional*. For the `part` properties, we can use an *intersection* of `N & Partial<T>`. This makes it possible to *infer* the generic type for each `part` but also to make them comply to the `Partial<T>` type.

Let's check some tests.

```
const res1 = func({ partA: { x: "" }, partB: { y: 0 }, partC: { z: new Date() } })
//    ^? const res1: { x: string; } & { y: number; } & { z: Date; }
```

The inference of `T` based on the input object seems to work as expected.

```
const res2 = func<{ x: string, y: number, z: Date }>({ 
  partA: { x: "0" }, 
  partB: { y: 0 }, 
  partC: { z: new Date() } 
})

const res3 = func<{ x: string, y: number, z: Date }>({ 
  partA: { x: "0" }, 
  partB: { y: "0" }, 
//         ^ Error: we violate Partial<T>
  partC: { z: new Date() } })
```

When we explitly provide a type for `T`, the constraint `Partial<T>` is enforced for each `part`.

The only drawback to keep in mind is the following scenario.

```
const res4 = func<{ x: string, y: number, z: Date }>({ 
  partA: { x: "0" }, 
  partB: { y: "0" }, 
  partC: { z: "0" } 
})
```

Each part has to be a `Partial<T>` but they don't have to add up to be a whole `T`. They can all be empty objects and TypeScript would be satisfied. This only is an issue when an explicit type for `T` is specified though.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAXDAPAWAFAxgFRgFMAPKIsAEwhgAoBBGAMhgCFmYBhASgBoc8jALwwkAazAgA7mH642MEeMky5eTotFgJ0sDgB8dAA4BDAE5QIaAN4xTF+mkYsACuagBLEwBt0+fbx27qxo7K7uXr7+gfZQnGga4RaRfoYAvtyKhoQiYAje3gCEANw4OKCQsGZEEACMmojItLaxjjC2JGgARF0waTHBNjAAnmgADH0DFvHtMABeaGBEUjAAIibktJlpfdw4APT7eHgAegD8MBXQMNV1Q50w0GYeYADmxX0ctqMweQC2ACMiGYPjsWLYFmsNkRQWVsFcqjUAEwNJDAdAdNBPF6vQI-f5AsyBSHrch9fTNIIOe7dMa9fpUqAhWY-CYM2IzCGLZZQzbbXZwhE3GoAZlRyAxMAe2LeeMWCEBwOJaFJRHJlNaNJgXTpk0ZzO+tPpUziQ0hSxWqq2nwyByOxwdjqdzpdrrd7o9jpOMAAomYzCAzGgpGqAG4eEDeaEwNzJHypOHlcDXW4AFnF6Mxjygz1lI3liqJ8xV0bSFJa7jaWZ1xv1Wpreo5Zu5luh1p2GSAA)

Comment: Thank you! The principle behind this absolutely works. Unfortunately, in my actual logic some of the "part" keys are mapped types, and this method doesn't appear to work in some of those cases. Still, answers the question as posted.

Comment: @Arii - feel free to post another question containing your whole problem with the mapped types :) I (and probably others too) would love to figure this one out too.